# Spring boot Unexpected character % code 37

Tags: java, json, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I am trying to read a string type attribute which contains json type data:

code react js :

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",JSON.stringify(FilterRegion))
```

code spring boot :

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
    public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody String filterRegion) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterRegionOne fro = mapper.readValue(filterRegion, FilterRegionOne.class);
    

        
        System.out.println(fro.isRfx());

         return null;      
    }
```

but when I try to display data in the console I got this error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('%' (code 37)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"%7B%22rfx%22%3Atrue%2C%22rfp%22%3Atrue%2C%22rfp_x%22%3Atrue%2C%22allclassification%22%3Atrue%2C%22eu%22%3Afalse%2C%22americas%22%3Afalse%2C%22aae%22%3Afalse%2C%22ger%22%3Afalse%2C%22eu2%22%3Afalse%2C%22latam%22%3Afalse%2C%22empty%22%3Afalse%2C%22allregion%22%3Afalse%2C%22idm%22%3Afalse%2C%22dig%22%3Afalse%2C%22eps%22%3Afalse%2C%22allpractice%22%3Afalse%2C%22c
```

please what i should to do now to display the data !

Comment: You're URL-encoding the JSON for some reason. Perhaps you need to set a content-type to prevent Axios from treating it as a form?

Comment: checkout examples here: https://github.com/axios/axios none of the examples uses  `JSON.stringify` as second param. so probably you should pass the data as object, not stringified.

Comment: What is the input of `filterRegion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For axios your second parameter needs to be the JSON object itself so remove the `JSON.stringify()`:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser", FilterRegion)
```

Also, in your controller, I would recommend parsing the JSON before it hits your method to have less boilerplate code:

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody FilterRegionOne filterRegion) {
    System.out.println(fro.isRfx());
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If FilterRegion is meant to be the request body of the POST request then you do not need to JSON stringify it when using axios, axios will handle that for you.

Also if you use the @RestController annotation at the class level instead of @Controller (cant see what you've used) then spring will handle the JSON mapping and you can access the POJO straight away

```
@PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
    public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody FilterRegionOne filterRegion {
    
    }
```